# Windows 10 sees second ssd hard drive but Ubuntu install does not

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, windows-10

I have Windows 10 installed and I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a second ssd drive. I boot up from the Ubuntu usb disk and when I use GParted it does not show up.

I went as far as taking all the other hard drives out but this ssd and all that would show up was the usb that I am booting Ubuntu 18.04 from.

In Windows-10 it shows up fine. I cleared up this second SSD drive and using DISKMGMT.MSC it looks like so [Linux(E:)]:
[image]

Ubuntu Troubleshooting Results:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                                  /rofs
loop1  squashf                                                  /snap/core/4486
loop2  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-3-26
loop3  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-calc
loop4  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-char
loop5  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-logs
loop6  squashf                                                  /snap/gnome-syst
sda                                                            
├─sda1                                                         
└─sda2 ntfs    DATA        7AECB19EECB154DB                    
sdb                                                            
└─sdb1 vfat    UBUNTU_18_0 E8D9-FF30                            /cdrom

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0    1.7G root  disk  brw-rw----
loop1   86.6M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop2    140M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop3    1.6M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop4   12.2M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop5     21M root  disk  brw-rw----
loop6    3.3M root  disk  brw-rw----
sda    931.5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   128M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda2 931.4G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb       15G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1    15G root  disk  brw-rw----
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
1      1049kB  135MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
2      135MB   1000GB  1000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: PNY USB 2.0 FD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  16.1GB  16.1GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: When the problematic SSD is connected (and powered on), please run the following three command lines, `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls` and edit the original question to show the result. Please indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code' (to make it easier to read).

Comment: Well, Ubuntu sees only the data disk (1TB) and the boot drive (16 GB). This is unusual (it can happen that partitions are not seen, but in your case not even the devices are seen. The next step is to check how they are seen by the BIOS/UEFI system (the menus, that you get into via a hotkey at boot).

Comment: @sudodus In the BIOS the drive shows up as a M.2 PCIe NVMe 256 GB SSD drive.

Comment: This is good information: an NVMe SSD drive. I have no experience of such a drive, but I have a few other SSD drives, that work well with Ubuntu. Let us hope that somebody who knows will see your question and help you :-) -- Maybe the following link can help [How to resolve an PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD Ubuntu/Kabuntu installation problem on your Dell PC](https://www.dell.com/support/article/se/sv/sedhs1/sln308883/how-to-resolve-an-pcie-nvme-m2-ssd-ubuntu-kabuntu-installation-problem-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en) or some other link found when you search the internet for **NVMe SSD ubuntu**